# How to push a new screen after user swipes RtoL in PageView when it is on last page

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

I have created an onboarding screen in flutter with 3 pages. What I'm trying to implement is that when user is on the last page (3rd page) and swipes right to left I want to push a screen (let's say Login Screen). How can I achieve such an effect? I tried wrapping the scaffold that the PageView widget is a child of with gesture detector and set its onHorizontalDragUpdate like so:

```
onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {}, //So the gestures don't clash
onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
  if (provider.currentPage + 1 == onBoardingData.length) {
    if (details.delta.direction > 0) {
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        RoutesName.loginScreen,
        (route) => false,
      );
    }
  }
},
```

It does not work. Any inputs are appreciated.

Here's the full code:

```
class OnBoardingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnBoardingScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<OnBoardingProvider>(
      builder: (_, provider, child) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {},
          onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
            if (provider.currentPage + 1 == onBoardingData.length) {
              if (details.delta.direction > 0) {
                Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  RoutesName.loginScreen,
                  (route) => false,
                );
              }
            }
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 180),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(Assets.introBG),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: PageView(
                    onPageChanged: (value) {
                      provider.pageChanged(value);
                    },
                    children: onBoardingData
                        .map((page) => _buildOnBoardingPage(page: page))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: onBoardingData
                          .map(
                            (page) => _buildIndicator(
                              condition: provider.currentPage ==
                                  onBoardingData.indexOf(page),
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70, right: 20),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          context,
                          RoutesName.loginScreen,
                          (route) => false,
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        provider.currentPage + 1 == onBoardingData.length
                            ? 'Done'
                            : 'Skip',
                        style: provider.currentPage + 1 == onBoardingData.length
                            ? titleSemiBold14(color: AppColor.colorFF689E)
                            : titleMedium14(color: AppColor.color258FC5),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

Column _buildOnBoardingPage({required OnBoardingModel page}) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Image.asset(page.image, fit: BoxFit.cover),
      WidgetUtil.spaceVertical(75),
      Text(page.title, style: headlineSemiBold22()),
      WidgetUtil.spaceVertical(15),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
        child: Text(
          page.content,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: titleRegular14(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

Widget _buildIndicator({required bool condition}) {
  return Container(
    width: Width.w8,
    height: Height.h8,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: Width.w4),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: condition ? AppColor.color258FC5 : AppColor.colorD9D9D9,
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(50),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```